# Android : Write in same file multiple times

Tags: android, sd-card, filewriter, bufferedwriter

New with Android. Sorry! I'm trying to create the following...

1. Wait for Timer to Finish. (No issues here).
2. Write time to a log file.
3. Activate Timer again.
4. Go back to step 1 & repeat.

The code for writing to the file is as follows...

```
    File file = new File("/sdcard/log.txt");
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
    writer.write(str);
    writer.newLine();
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
```

The code is only writing the last .write in the file! The previous WRITE is removed. I suspect that its creating a new file everytime and writing the latest line. I tried with FOS and OSW but with same results! Please help, am stuck on this one for almost 48 hours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`FileWriter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html) in append mode.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true));
```

Comment: Thanks mate. Stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 2):

You may want to use this constructor for FileWriter :

[FileWriter (File file,
          boolean append)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29)

> By using the second argument as `true` then the bytes will be written to the end of the file rather than the beginning.

In your code use : `BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file,true));`